# Could not load .mat file with `scipy.io.loadmat`

Tags: python, scipy

Could not load .mat file with `scipy.io.loadmat`

```
import scipy.io
scipy.io.loadmat('D:\Shishkin\LargeData\e4_datasets\e4epochs')

Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)
```

I've get this error with all `.mat` files. Scipy v0.17

Answer (score 0):

.mat files are (according to [here](http://mloss.org/community/blog/2009/nov/19/matlabtm-73-file-format-is-actually-hdf5-and-can-b/)) hdf5 formatted. There is a python library [here](http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/file.html) for making use of hdf5.

Comment: But I'm successfully load .mat file before updating scipy

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand.

Comment: I had scipy v0.16, and I successfully loaded .mat files with loadmat function. Then I've got scipy v0.17 and  got error mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem:

`"Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)"` with `scipy.io.loadmat`
when using scipy from `Anaconda2 4.0.0 (Windows7 Professional 64 bit)`.
I uninstalled Anaconda, and installed a new version: `Anaconda2 4.3.0.1`. The problem went away.